# Overriding activity transitions for every activity

Tags: android

I've created some animations for activity transition. But the code for overriding each activity's transition is kind of boilerplate code, how can I overcome this, meaning writing the code once and being applied to every activity?I'm guessing something with inheritage ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public void transition {
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_down_in, R.anim.push_down_out);
    }
}

class SubActivitiy extends BaseActivity {
    public void applyTransition {
        transition();
    }

}
```

Comment: perfect! thx so much, I have thought activities and activityFragments that I want to extend that means I have to make on ParentClass for each type right?

Comment: yes,what the same thing that subclass would do,just do it in the ParentClass.